# Detect vertical scrollbar present or not using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an HTML report, where I've applied style as  **"overflow:auto"**  The data fills dynamically so I need to detect if there is a **vertical scrollbar** existing or not in the report.
After researching over many forums, which all suggest comparing the `scrollHeight` and     `clientHeight`, I tried this:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  var myReport = document.getElementById("report_id");
  if (myReport.scrollHeight > myReport.clientHeight) { 
  alert("has a scrollbar");   
  } else {
  alert("has NO scrollbar");   
  }
  });
```

This does not work.
The result is always true, i.e "has a scrollbar", even when there's no vertical scrollbar.

Please suggest.

P.S: The above code is just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var outerHeight = $("#report_id").outerHeight();
   var scrollHeight = $('#report_id')[0].scrollHeight
   if (outerHeight < scrollHeight) {
       alert("has a scrollbar"); 
   }
   else
   {
      alert("has NO scrollbar"); 
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's now going for the else part everytime :(
I have tried many combinations. scrollHeight, clientHeight, innerHeight. No success

Comment: I checked by displaying the scrollHeight and outerHeight in alert. They're both the same, whatever the region height is. 
I have fixed the max-height for the report as 480 px. And I do not want to detect scrollbar presence on the basis of region height being less than 480 px due to some issues.
@ankit, What might be the issue that both the heights are same?

Comment: My table was inside a region, so I had to use this:  $("#report_id tbody") and it worked. thanks @ankit.

Comment: i have same problem want to detect if the document has scroll or not but my project does not have jquery included. any solution in vanilla javascript ?